How do I disable music from playing on HomePod?
We use a HomePod for a disabled person to make phone calls using voice commands. Sometimes this results in playing loud music instead of making the call.
How do I completely disable the service that plays music? I found nothing in the Home app on iOS 17.

I'm not sure that a HomePod is the best choice for your use case, but leaving that aside, you would have to unsubscribe from Apple Music in the Apple Account that the device is associated with.

You can say that again. Unfortunately you can't always reason with people ‍♂️ Thanks for the suggestion. I couldn't find a subscription but I did at least log out from Music where possible.

I don't think that just logging out on other devices will make any difference. The HomePod streams Apple Music directly from your account. You would have to unsubscribe: https://support.apple.com/en-us/118428
